# Adobe Media Server DVR only 5 second recording

Tags: apache-flex, streaming, adobe, flash-builder, flash-media-server

I have a strange problem. I have an application built in Flash Builder.

When I record to **Flash Media Server** I don't have any issues, it'll do DVR for as long as I want. But when I record to Adobe Media Server, the recording is only 5 seconds long.

```
ns = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.client = new Object();
    userUID = UIDUtil.createUID();
    ns.attachAudio (mic);
    ns.attachCamera (camera);
    ns.publish( "demo" + userUID, "record" );
```

Later I can play the recording, timestamp says that it's a 5 second archive, but it'll really keep playing the recorded video.

Same code, just different server.

Has anyone had this problem when **migrating to Adobe Media Server from Flash Media Server**?

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. I'm doing some updates to an old video chat product that I believe was created on FMS 3.5. Recently the client updated the server to 4.5.1 and around that time, we started noticing that when playing the videos back, the flv player scrubber will only show 5 seconds. Sometimes it will stop playing after 5 seconds and sometimes the Play Again button will show up over the video but the video will play for a while longer. It almost seems like some metadata is not getting saved in the video file, or it can't read the length so it only shows a scrubber for 5 s.

Comment: Hey awesome, i'm not the only one. Are you with AWS?